# Microsoft Academic Graph API currently accepting new subscribers?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am attempting to subscribe to the Project Academic Knowledge API at this link

https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/products/5636d970e597ed0690ac1b3f

I'm getting:

We're unable to complete your request
Microsoft account is experiencing technical problems. Please try again later.

I'm wondering if this is actually a technical problem or if they have disabled new subscribers to this API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this message because you're using the wrong portal to subscribe, try subscribing [here](https://labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/en-us/project-academic-knowledge) and then you'll be able to use the keys generated by that portal [here](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56332331778daf02acc0a50b/operations/565d9001ca73072048922d97)